# How to handle URL rewrites for www.username.domain.net

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting

I converted an old site from custom php to drupal, but I am having a hard time getting some URL redirects to work. The old site used URLs like "*username*.domain.net", but under drupal I've had to use a URL structure like "www.domain.net/profile/*username*"  ("*username*" being a placeholder for a member's name).

I have "*username*.domain.net" redirecting to "www.domain.net/profile/*username*" just fine, but the regex fails to handle URLs like "www.*username*.domain.net" (resulting in lots of duplicate content).

In my .htaccess file:

```
# redirect old user subdomains (user.domain.net > www.domain.net/profile/user)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net/profile/%1/ [R=301,L]

# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I need some help figuring out how to handle redirects for URLs that have both a "www" and "*username*" prefix (i.e. www.*username*.domain.com), so it redirects properly to www.domain.net/profile/*username*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# redirect old user subdomains ((www.)user.domain.net > www.domain.net/profile/user)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www).*)\.domain\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.net/profile/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the subdomain redirects don't work at all.